# Flatlist ref values like scrollToEnd throw error of its not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I m using flatlist for render tabbar and at certain click it need to be scroll to some value so that i m created ref to scrollTo certain value like scrollToEnd.

```js
 // ref declaration was here
 const containerRef = useRef();

 
 
// This flatlist attached ref as containerRef
 <Animated.FlatList
        data={TABDATA}
        ref={containerRef}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        keyExtractor={(_, ind) => _.id.toString()}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: scrollX}}}],
          {useNativeDriver: true},
        )}
        renderItem={({item: {Component}, index}) => {
          return (
            <View style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH}}>
              {/* Header */}
              <Component />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />


// When tab is clicked i need to scrollTo certain value

  const onPressTab = () => {
    console.log('onPrees Tab', containerRef);
    containerRef.current.scrollToEnd();
    // or 
    // containerRef.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: some value })
  };
```

Why its throwing scrollToEnd is not function

Any help please

Comment: Is FlatList rendered at the time on calling scrollToEnd? Can you console.log value of containerRef to see possible changes in value.

Comment: I console log that but scrollToEnd function was not there